# SPARQL query returns different results depending on the order of statements

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have a SPARQL query which returns the most specific common classes of two resources.

When I try to run it on https://dbpedia.org/sparql, sometimes it returns nothing, and other times it returns the classes I want.

I have noticed it is related to the order of the statements in the query.

This is not a desirable behavior because, when I execute the query, I expect it to have the same results regardless of the order in which I input the URIs of the resources.

Has anyone experienced this problem and found a solution for it?

**Queries**

The following query works properly, returning http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film and http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Wikidata:Q11424 as results:

```
SELECT ?lcs
WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)> a ?class1 .
  ?class1 rdfs:subClassOf* ?lcs .
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo> a ?class2 .
  ?class2 rdfs:subClassOf* ?lcs .

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo> a ?class3 .
    ?class3 rdfs:subClassOf* ?sublcs .
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)> a ?class4 .
    ?class4 rdfs:subClassOf* ?sublcs .
    ?sublcs  rdfs:subClassOf ?lcs
  }

  FILTER strstarts(str(?lcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")
}
```

However, the following query returns nothing:

```
SELECT ?lcs
WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo> a ?class1 .
  ?class1 rdfs:subClassOf* ?lcs .
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)> a ?class2 .
  ?class2 rdfs:subClassOf* ?lcs .

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo> a ?class3 .
    ?class3 rdfs:subClassOf* ?sublcs .
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)> a ?class4 .
    ?class4 rdfs:subClassOf* ?sublcs .
    ?sublcs  rdfs:subClassOf ?lcs
  }

  FILTER strstarts(str(?lcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")
}
```

Comment: For some reasons, the second query is more expensive, and Virtuoso can't find what you want within query execution time.
But for what reasons... I guess the reason is that the number of `rdf:type`s of *Finding Nemo* (~55) is more than of the number of `rdf:type`s of *Ice Age* (~35).
By way, *SQL* executions plans of your queries are slightly different (check *Generate SPARQL compilation report (instead of executing the query)* to see them).

Comment: Don't forget that Virtuoso has the *anytime feature* and the default timeout in the web interface is 30s.

Comment: And as StansilavKralin said, although semantically equivalent, different orders of triple patterns can result in a different query execution plan. That's the most difficult part of a triple store by the way and finding "the best" isn't trivial (even this even exists)

Comment: By the way, you could also add a filter `FILTER strstarts(str(?sublcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")` to the `NOT EXISTS` part as you're interested in the DBpedia ontology only.

Comment: Or even more performant should be using `?lcs a owl:Class .` to the first part of the query. Only for DBpedia classes those schema triples are loaded.

Comment: Adding `?lcs a owl:Class .` does indeed speed things up enormously, but this will leave out `dbo:Wikidata:Q11424` which is only described as `owl:equivalentClass dbo:Film` and not explicitly as `a owl:Class`.

Comment: @AKSW Adding `FILTER strstarts(str(?sublcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")` to the `NOT EXISTS` part indeed made the results show up.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Good point, that might be the reason it is more expansive than the other query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're running your queries on a public endpoint, which has a variety of self-protection settings in place. This means that expensive queries may produce partial or no results, while inexpensive queries may produce full results.  You can set up your own mirror endpoint ([quick-and-easy on Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK)) with no such protections, and you should see equivalent results from equivalent queries.
2. @AKSW provided a tweak to your query that quickly produces full results --

   > add `FILTER strstarts(str(?sublcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology")` to the `NOT EXISTS` part

   (see the [query form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%3Flcs%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFinding_Nemo%3E%20a%20%3Fclass1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fclass1%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Flcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIce_Age_%282002_film%29%3E%20a%20%3Fclass2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fclass2%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Flcs%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFinding_Nemo%3E%20a%20%3Fclass3%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass3%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Fsublcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIce_Age_%282002_film%29%3E%20a%20%3Fclass4%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass4%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Fsublcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fsublcs%20%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3Flcs%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fsublcs%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Flcs%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) and [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Flcs%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFinding_Nemo%3E%20a%20%3Fclass1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fclass1%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Flcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIce_Age_%282002_film%29%3E%20a%20%3Fclass2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fclass2%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Flcs%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFinding_Nemo%3E%20a%20%3Fclass3%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass3%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Fsublcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FIce_Age_%282002_film%29%3E%20a%20%3Fclass4%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass4%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf*%20%3Fsublcs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fsublcs%20%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20%3Flcs%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fsublcs%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20strstarts%28str%28%3Flcs%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20))

   ```
   SELECT ?lcs
   WHERE
   {
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo>  a  ?class1  .
     ?class1  rdfs:subClassOf*  ?lcs  .
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)>  a  ?class2  .
     ?class2  rdfs:subClassOf*  ?lcs  .

     FILTER NOT EXISTS {
       <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo>  a  ?class3  .
       ?class3  rdfs:subClassOf*  ?sublcs  .
       <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ice_Age_(2002_film)>  a  ?class4  .
       ?class4  rdfs:subClassOf*  ?sublcs .
       ?sublcs  rdfs:subClassOf  ?lcs 
       FILTER strstarts( str(?sublcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology" )
     }

     FILTER strstarts( str(?lcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology" )
   }
   ```

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), which powers the DBpedia endpoint, and the [AMI referenced above](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK). They also employ me.)

Comment: Yes, adding `FILTER strstarts( str(?sublcs), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology" )` works.

Comment: I didn't know there was such a setting, I thought it would give me a timeout error if the query was taking too long. Good to know.