# Order of expressions in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, triplestore

Is there any difference between the tow queries below?

```
select distinct ?i 
where{
    ?i rdf:type <http://foo/bar#A>. 
    FILTER EXISTS {
        ?i <http://foo/bar#hasB> ?b.
        ?b rdf:type <http://foo/bar#B1>.
    }            
}


select distinct ?i 
    where{
        FILTER EXISTS {
            ?i <http://foo/bar#hasB> ?b.
            ?b rdf:type <http://foo/bar#B1>.
        }
        ?i rdf:type <http://foo/bar#A>.             
    }
```

There are differences regarding performance or results?

Comment: No, there is no difference in the result, it's just a filter on the bindings of `?i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you do not need `FILTER EXISTS`. You can rewrite your query with basic graph pattern (a set of regular triple patterns). But let's suppose you are using `FILTER NOT EXISTS` or something like.

### Results

In general, [order matters](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Order_Matters).

However, top-down evaluation semantics plays role mostly in case of `OPTIONAL`, and that is not your case. Thus, results should be the same.

Top-down evaluation semantics can be overridden by [bottom-up](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics) evaluation semantics. Fortunately, bottom-up semantics [doesn't prescribe](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#scopeFilters) to evaluate `FILTER` logically first though it is possible in case of `FILTER EXISTS` and `FILTER NOT EXISTS`.

SPARQL Algebra [representation](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) is the same for both queries:

```
(prefix ((rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
         (foobar: <http://foo/bar#>))
  (distinct
    (project (?i)
      (filter (exists
                 (bgp
                   (triple ?i foobar:B ?b)
                   (triple ?b rdf:type foobar:B1)
                 ))
        (bgp (triple ?i rdf:type foobar:A))))))
```

### Performance

Naively following top-down semantics, an engine should evaluate `?i a foobar:A` first.

- You are lucky, if there exists only one binding for `?i`.
- You are not so lucky, if there exist millions of bindings for `?i` whereas subpattern is much more selective.

Fortunately, optimizers try to reorder patterns depending on their selectivity. However, predictions can be erroneous.

By the way, the `rdf:type` predicate [is said to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39751134/7879193) a performance killer in Virtuoso.

### Results vs Performance

Results can be different, if an endpoint has a query execution time limit and flushes partial results when timeout is reached: [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48188730/7879193).

Comment: The "order matters" link has moved: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/SPARQL_Order_Matters

Comment: Oh, also "bottom-up": https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics